# error :com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read the below json and map to the model object.

Model class:

```
 public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<String> messages;
}
```

Below is the sample code used to map the json to model (MyModelData.java)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String jsonInString = "{\"age\":33,\"messages\":[\"msg 1\",\"msg 2\"],\"name\":\"mkyong\"}";
        User user1 = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, User.class);
        System.out.println(user1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ex " + e);
    }
```

Below is the exception :

```
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "age" (class com.dsr.User), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (String)"{"age":33,"messages":["msg 1","msg 2"],"name":"mkyong"}"; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.dsr.User["age"])
```

When mapping the json string to the model object it is showing the above exception. The User class has age property defined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only issue with your code but for `ID:4` in the JSON after `Claim related to issueID` you are missing a closing speech mark.

Comment: Thankyou, but it is not the issue, It was the copy paste problem while i was raising this question.